# Error in select statement using C# - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, oledb

I have the following code:

```
string sSelect = @"select a.nume, a.cui, b.suma, b.perioada, c.nume_produs from client as a
                   left join client_produs as b on a.id_client = b.id_client
                   left join produs as c on b.id_produs = c.id_produs";
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cSelect = new OleDbCommand(sSelect, con);
OleDbDataReader clientsInfo = cSelect.ExecuteReader();
```

The purpose of the above select statement is to retrieve all the information stored in the database.

The problem is I am getting an error :
"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'a.id_client = b.id_client left join produs as c on b.id_produs = c.id_produs'.'"

I cannot find the reason why and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you put the entire string that defines sSelect on a single line?

Comment: What database? OLEDB is the driver API, not a specific database.

Comment: @Russ, I managed to solve it by putting parantheses aroung the first join.

Comment: Which RDBMS? @Russ the @ symbol means a multiline string